# Angular forms - access FormArray in child component template

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a component that takes several `FormControl`s and `FormArray`s as inputs. I'm accessing the `FormControl`s from the child component like this:

```
[formControl]="control"
```

This works fine, but I can't find a way to do the same with a `FormArray`. There doesn't appear to be a directive for it. I would like to avoid passing in a bunch of strings and accessing via `formControlName` and `formArrayName` if possible. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** there was a type error, jsut corrected

You can use a FormArray like a FormGroup, but be carefully with the "notation", if normally we use [formGroup]="i", now we use [formGroup]="group".

It's only think about what is myFormArray.controls

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormArray">
  <div *ngFor="let group of myFormArray.controls;let i=index" [formGroup]="group">
    <input formControlName="prop1">
    <div *ngIf="group.get('prop1').invalid">Prop1 Required</div>
    <input formControlName="prop2"/>
    <div *ngIf="group.get('prop2').invalid">Prop2 Required</div>
  </div>
</form>

myFormArray=new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      prop1:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      prop2:new FormControl('',Validators.required)
    })
  ])
```

If your formArray is a FormArray of controls use directly formControl

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormArray2">
  <div *ngFor="let group of myFormArray2.controls">
    <input [formControl]="group">
    <div *ngIf="group.invalid">Required</div>
  </div>
</form>

myFormArray2=new FormArray([
    new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    new FormControl('',Validators.required)
  ])
```

See in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j78vzf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)