# Angular7 ControlValueAccesor as FormArray

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to develop a reusable list component, which returns a list of objects, a plain list of objects, those should be a assigned to key in a formGroup object value.

Is there a way to do a custom control in Angular which is a list?

Here is what I tried and what I intent to do, hope the code is self explanatory.

```
// PARENT COMPONENT 
<div [formGroup]="form" [ngSubmit]="submit()">
    <custom-list formControlName="profiles"></custom-list>
    <custom-list formControlName="groups"></custom-list>
    <custom-list formControlName="users"></custom-list>

    <button>Submit</button>
</div>

@Component(...)
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        // Method One
        this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
          profiles: ['', Validators.required],
          groups: ['', Validators.required],
          users: ['', Validators.required]
        });

        // Method Two. Don't know how is should be or if it will work?
        this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
          profiles: this._formBuilder.array([]),
          groups: this._formBuilder.array([]),
          users: this._formBuilder.array([])
        });
    }
}
```

Then the child (the list component is defined as this)

```
// CHILD COMPONENT
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-list',
  providers: [{
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomListComponent),
      multi: true
  }]
})
export class CustomListComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor { 
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
          elements: this._formBuilder.array([], Validators.required)
        });
    }

    writeValue(val: any): void {
        val && this.form.setControl('elements', this._formBuilder.array(val));
    }
}
```

The form value should looks like this

```
{
    profiles: [{id: 1, name: "profile 1"}, {id: 2, name: "profile 2"}],
    groups: [{id: 1, name: "group 1"}, {id: 2, name: "group 2"}],
    users: [{id: 1, name: "user 1"}, {id: 2, name: "user 2"}]
}
```

Doing it that way it worked, BUT the list added an extra key to the form group keys, which is the group I added to the child form.

```
{
        profiles: { 
           elements: [{id: 1, name: "profile 1"}, {id: 2, name: "profile 2"}] 
           },
        groups: { 
           elements: [{id: 1, name: "group 1"}, {id: 2, name: "group 2"}]
           },
        groups: { 
           elements: [{id: 1, name: "user 1"}, {id: 2, name: "user 2"}] 
          }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641362/angular-forms-access-formarray-in-child-component-template/55649089#55649089. Just pass a FormArray form.get('profiles'), form.get('groups') and form.get('users')

Answer (score 3):

extended my comment,  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radcgz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
Your children

```
    <div *ngFor="let group of myFormArray.controls;let i=index" [formGroup]="group">
        <input formControlName="prop1">
    <div *ngIf="group.get('prop1').invalid">Prop1 Required</div>
    <input formControlName="prop2"/>
    <div *ngIf="group.get('prop2').invalid">Prop2 Required</div>
  @Input()myFormArray:FormArray
```

Your parent

```
<div [formGroup]="form" [ngSubmit]="submit()">
    <custom-list [myFormArray]="form.get('profiles')"></custom-list>
    <custom-list [myFormArray]="form.get('groups')></custom-list>
    <custom-list [myFormArray]="form.get('users')></custom-list>

    <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: that looks pretty good. Let me give it a try. In fact there is no need for ControlValueAccessor to be used

Comment: Be carefully, there are an error in the in the stackblitz , the `@Input() myArray:string` must be `@Input() myArray:FormArray`