# Angular Reactive Forms- Create a component that returns an array as value

Tags: angular

I have a root component (called ComponentA) which has a formGroup and inside this formGroup one formArray. This formArray I want to be built in another component. Is there any way to create a component which returns a formArray value?

Comment: Do you mean that from the form you want your component to only return the array (not the formArray)?

Comment: Most probably your logic is wrong here because you are thinking the opposite way. The correct approach would be to have a child component with an `@Input() formControl: FormControl`. There, from the parent component you would pass in the formControl from the formgroup you made

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641362/angular-forms-access-formarray-in-child-component-template/55649089#55649089 I put how use a formArray as top control. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55895193/angular7-controlvalueaccesor-as-formarray using the idea use a child component. My Idea it's always the same. The form is created in the parent component, you pass as Input hte formArray

Comment: @Eliseo, you were right, I used your approach, Thanks